# How to replace a shielded quotes with {}

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-group

I have such a code for replacing quotes with {}

```
$message = preg_replace('/"([^"]*)"/', "{$1}", $message);
```

How I can to modify it that for replacing of shielded quotes in the text like this

> \"some text\"

Also desirable that quotes inside this text remains the same.
For example this text

> \"some text with the string "123"\"

after replacing should look like this

> {some text with the string "123"}

Comment: Like this? `^(.*?)(\\")(.*)(\\")(.*?)$` replace with `$1{$3}$5`

Comment: Does provided example happen inside a larger text?

Comment: @ctwheels Yes, like this.

Answer (score 4):

It's like matching a quoted string in a revers manner, there's a workaround to match right parts:

```
~(\\")([^\\]*(?:\\[^"][^\\]*)*)(\\")~
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/WfuK7L/1)

PHP:

```
$re = <<< 'RE'
~(\\")([^\\]*(?:\\[^"][^\\]*)*)(\\")~
RE;

echo preg_replace($re, '{$2}', $str);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's works fine. But is there a possibility to modify this expression for replacing not shielded quotes too?
That is, string like `\"some text with the string "123"\" and "string"` after replacing should look like this `{some text with the string "123"} and {string}`

Comment: With test code it works well, but with the same input from my form using `ckeditor` the result looks like that: `\»some text with the string «123»\» and «string»`

Comment: I'm not sure what's in middle that changes output but for sure you have to spend time to find it. @evgeny_s

Answer (score -1):

i guess this will work to you:

```
$message = preg_replace("/^\\\"(.*)\\\"$/", "{$1}", $message);
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, code-only answers are frowned upon.  Please also provide an explanation to OP to explain your answer.  [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)